# NVMe device on Linux takes a lot time to appear

Tags: linux, linux-kernel, linux-device-driver, nvme

I am using a Linux host (SLES 15 SP2 with kernel version 5.3.18-24.78-default) in a SAN environment supporting NVMe devices, and so can dynamically add/remove the devices.

I noticed that when I have configured 4000+ NVMe devices to my linux host, and add more devices, the kernel recognizes immediately that a device is added by putting below messages in dmesg -

```
[49701.992704] nvme nvme2: rescanning namespaces.
[49701.992716] nvme nvme1: rescanning namespaces.
[49701.992731] nvme nvme3: rescanning namespaces.
[49701.992746] nvme nvme4: rescanning namespaces.
```

But, the actual sysfs and /dev and other device files appear only after a delay, and sometimes this delay is larger than a minute.

I would like to understand why this delay, and is there a way to tune it. Moreover, is this delay dependent on CPU/memory available/usage ?

If somebody can help or give pointer, it will be great.

Thanks  & Regards

Comment: Please add the program you are writing as a [mre] to the question.

Comment: The simple program could be trying to access the nvme namespace as soon as it is added to NVMe controller, but that fails because the namespace is discovered but kernel takes "some" extra time to create the required sysfs files, which further delays creation of /dev files due to unavailability of uevent file.

Comment: 4 **thousand** devices? So, each of them requires time to initiate, right? You are telling about a minute, let’s assume the quadratic algorithm, so O(n^2) = 60s, which means that something may be rewritten in a better way.

Comment: All those 4000 devices are already initiated. The delay is in the new device.. I am unable to understand why adding just one device whether it is 10th or 100th or 4001st will see different delays in creating related device files especially when host is completely idle when a device is added.

Comment: Because it’s an algorithmic issue. You understand, I hope, that adding a device is O(1) in the very best case. If the code was written by millennials, it may be O(N) or even worse. Look into the code, analyse what it’s doing.